# How to compare data in two tables and display data from one table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables with the following structure:

```
categories
    id
    status
    name
    created
posts
    id
    status
    category_id
    title
    excerpt
    featured_image
    created
user_authors
    id
    status
    author_name
    created
```

I am using the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT posts.id, posts.category_id, user_authors.author_name, posts.user_author_id, posts.title, posts.post_slug, posts.featured_image, posts.excerpt, posts.created FROM posts, user_authors INNER JOIN categories ON(posts.category_id = categories.id) WHERE posts.status = 1 AND categories.name LIKE = %".$_GET['category']."%";
```

What i am trying to do is, i am having an url `www.xyz.com/technology`

where technology is a parameter(category) according to that i will select the posts to display.

I am showing the data where `posts.category_id = categories.id AND category_name = $_GET['category']`

I am not able to extract any data, I am confused that whether my query is wrong or my logic is wrong?

Can anyone help me solving this logic?

Comment: How the `posts` to `user_authors` relationship held? I could not see a connecting keys between those two tables. Does `id` in `user_authors` table refers to `id` in `posts` table?

Comment: i am displaying data so i just need the author name to display that this post has been posted by so and so author.

Comment: Does `id` in `user_authors` table refers to `id` in `posts table`? If it is not, then your query is doing a cross join where each post gets all of entries from user authors, which I don't think the correct behavior you are expecting.

Comment: yes it refers as you're saying.

Comment: whee is the join to categories table??

Comment: tag it with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `=` with `LIKE` clause and you did not write any relation between `posts` and `user_authors` tables.

The correct query should be:

```
$query = "SELECT posts.id, posts.category_id, user_authors.author_name, posts.user_author_id, posts.title, posts.post_slug, posts.featured_image, posts.excerpt, posts.created FROM posts INNER JOIN user_authors ON (user_authors.id = posts.user_author_id) INNER JOIN categories ON (posts.category_id = categories.id) WHERE posts.status = 1 AND categories.name LIKE '%".$_GET['category']."%'";
```

If you are finding only for one `categories.name` you can remove `%` from query, this will help mysql to search records if `categories.name` column has index.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a `=` with `LIKE` which is not correct in [mysql](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp). The correct way should be,

```
categories.name LIKE '%". $_GET['category']."%'"
```

Note the removal of `=` and enclosing with `'`

---

Edit:

According to your reply the new query should look like below.

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.category_id, user_authors.author_name, posts.user_author_id, posts.title, posts.post_slug, posts.featured_image, posts.excerpt, posts.created 
FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON posts.category_id = categories.id
INNER JOIN user_authors ON posts.id = user_authors.id 
WHERE posts.status = 1 AND categories.name LIKE '%".$_GET['category']."%'"
```

Comment: still its showing `Unknown column 'posts.category_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav updated the answer with new query joining posts and user_authors

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the user_author from the select, as there is no join to link the three tables in your command.

Comment: I would have nested the user_author table lookup as done in this example. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_inner2

Comment: The unknown column error was because posts.category_id doesn't exist in user_author